(Fantasy/Kids/Horror?) movie/TV show involving kids going to a faerie realm
This has been bothering me for years... I remember this scene so vividly, and I keep thinking it was from a movie. Although it might have been from a TV show. Or I might have dreamt the thing. In any case, I want to see if anyone else recognizes it. Sorry for the vague-ness.
I watched older movies as a kid, but I remember this being in color, so honestly, it could be anywhere from 60's to early 90's for this range. It was in English, and came out in America.
I think there was two kids, there might have been just one; who were friends with... something supernatural, I'm going to call them 'faeries' for the sake of this description. It might have been trolls, or just generic fantasy stuff. 
Anyways, the kids go to the faerie realm (I'm pretty sure they had to be lead, and it was a different area then the 'real' world) and they go to this... I'm going to call it an arena. It had the steeped seats that were above a center ring. The center ring was filled with... I think mud? Pretty sure mud, and it bubbled and looked gross. (It could have been poop, or a different color, but I'm 85% sure it was brown)
After a bit, this sphere rose up out of the mud, and it had a human face in it, but it was dripping mud as well, and I think mud was coming out of it's mouth.
I also think the fae creatures were... calling for it, worshiping it, something. I remember them chanting, and they wanted it to be there.
One of the fae creatures gets chosen. And I remember it getting... killed somehow? Don't remember if it jumps into the mud willingly, or gets eating by the mud sphere thing or what. And I think the kids were freaked out about it...

This sounds kinda Peter Pan-ish. I'll see if the almighty Google turns anything up.

I know you say fantasy faerie kink of movie, but i found a very similar foto of this sphere with human face in "Invaders from Mars" there are one from 1953 and other from 86.

The Neverending Story II: The Next Chapter (1990)
https://octotea.files.wordpress.com/2016/05/tqqhwc.gif?w=1000

I just barely found it two minutes ago (took me years)
http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0093116/reviews 
The Great Land of Small

can you edit your answer to explain why you think this is the movie?

I used the link, and while it didn't sound familiar, I did a google image search on the title, and came up with a couple images, and this clip: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QGbNTCSIrfg which is the very scene I was thinking of. It's not as goopy and muddy as I remember it though, but that's definitely it!

Could it be The Great Land of Small?  http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0093116/?ref_=ttmd_md_nm
